# When does material fail if rapid stress applied for very short time?

Tags: material-science, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

There are elaborate material failure or yield criteria when force (and so stress) is acting quasi-statically. Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_failure_theory) describing material failure theories. In many tension testing experiments, the specimen is loaded quasi-statically, yield (for ductile materials) and failure can be predicted from one of these theories.

How material yield or failure is described if the force (or stress) acts very rapidly? For example, if a hammer is dropped on floor, there would be very high stresses developing, but they last for a very short time. Though stresses developed may be orders of magnitude compared to yield strength of hammer, it doesn't break. Same with floor.